# Bitcoin Best Practices by the Bitcoin Foundation

Tags: standard, bitcoin-foundation

The [Bitcoin Foundation](https://www.bitcoinfoundation.org)'s Executive Director, Peter Vessenes, in his [open letter](https://www.bitcoinfoundation.org/about/letter) states that the Foundation is aiming to

> Publish a set of best practices for businesses transacting in Bitcoin, covering topics from accounting to physical and digital security

Is there any information on how this set of best practices is being developed, who is working on it and whether any individual can contribute to the works?

Answer (score 1):

I put together a Kindle book, [Bitcoin Step by Step](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A1CUQQU), that covers some best practices.  When I was writing I searched the web for what ever I could find trying to make sure what I suggested was indeed the current best practices.  [You can find it on Kindle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A1CUQQU).

Comment: Could you provide a link to the kindle book and possibly its title or other search terms?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Bitcoin-Step-by-ebook/dp/B00A1CUQQU/

Comment: The name of the book is Bitcoin Step by Step and I recently wrote it.  The idea was to take a new user through the steps of setting up a wallet in a secure manner.  Then how to fund their wallet and how to extract funds back to a currency.  Please check out the Amazon page for a more descriptive overview of the book.